# C++ variadic macro or variadic template?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I would like to simplify some code and would like help figuring out if there is a way to do it with a variadic macro or better yet a variadic template. The sample code below will show what I am trying to do.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

// Class that registers an external function handler
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args> class Redirector
{
    const std::string &m_funcName;

public:
    typedef ReturnType (*FuncTy)(Args...);
    Redirector(const std::string &functionName, FuncTy pfunc) : m_funcName(functionName)
    {
        GetMap()[functionName] = pfunc;
    }

    ~Redirector()
    {
        auto i = GetMap().find(m_funcName);
        if (i == GetMap().end()) return;
        i->second = nullptr;
        GetMap().erase(m_funcName);
    }

    static std::map<std::string, FuncTy> &GetMap()
    {
        static std::map<std::string, Redirector::FuncTy> _map;
        return _map;        
    }

    static FuncTy &GetHandler(std::string functionName)
    {
        auto i = GetMap().find(functionName);
        if (i == GetMap().end()) {
            std::cerr << functionName << " is not present in the list of functions to be redirected.\n";
            exit(-1);
        }
        return i->second;
    }
};

// Actual functions we want to call
void foo(int a)
{
    std::cout << "foo:" << a << std::endl;
}

void bar(double b, int *p)
{
    std::cout << "bar:" << b << " and " << p << std::endl;
}


// Redirection Handlers 
void foo1(int A)
{
    auto handle = Redirector<void, int>::GetHandler("_FOO");
    handle(A);
}
Redirector<void, int>_FOOHandler("_FOO", reinterpret_cast<Redirector<void, int>::FuncTy>(foo));

void bar1(double B, int *P)
{
    auto handle = Redirector<void, double, int *>::GetHandler("_BAR");
    handle(B, P);
}
Redirector<void, double, int *>_BARHandler("_BAR", reinterpret_cast<Redirector<void, double, int *>::FuncTy>(bar));

// Main 
int main()
{
    int i = 7;

    foo1(i);
    bar1(3.4, &i);

    return 0;
}
```

Assume there will be lots of foo1 & bar1 functions that are needed and all of them would do the same just would take different number of parameters and different types of parameters. The following is not a working macro but just an idea to show what I am trying to do:

```
define REGISTER_HANDLER(NAME,PARAMS)\
void NAME ## 1(PARAMS)\                                                                              
{\                                                                                                  
    auto handle = Redirector<PARAM_TYPES>::GetHandler("_"#NAME);\                                   
    handle(PARAM_NAMES);\                                                                                      
}\                                                                                                   
Redirector<PARAM_TYPES>NAME ## Handler("_"#NAME, reinterpret_cast<Redirector<PARAM_TYPES>::FuncTy>(foo));\

REGISTER_HANDLER(foo,int a);
REGISTER_HANDLER(bar,double b,int *p);
```

I have looked into using the `__VA_ARGS__` for macros, but I can't quite figure out how to get just the parameter types or just the parameter names.

Comment: So you have some variadic templates. Are they working? If not, what exactly isn't working? It isn't clear to me why one would even consider any kind of macro for this task.

Comment: The example code is indeed using variadic templates and is working as expected. What I am trying to figure out how to do is make the creation of foo1 and bar1 easier. Think about having hundreds such redirector functions. They all could take different parameters. I am trying to reduce the creation to just a single line using a macro. I am hoping there is an even better solution if they can be made into a single template function that can handle the redirection.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? You have a map of string function names to function pointers, and you wrap access to each individual element of the map in its own named function. Looks like you introduce a map only to defeat its purpose. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is a small part of a much bigger beast. I was trying to simplify the question to the part I need help with. In reality there are different objects which register their own set of redirectors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I found a solution that works:

```
#define REGISTER_HANDLER(NAME,...)                                                                                          \
template<typename... Args>                                                                                                  \
void NAME##1(Args... args)                                                                                                  \
{                                                                                                                           \
    auto handle = Redirector<void, Args...>::GetHandler("_"#NAME);                                                          \
    handle((args)...);                                                                                                      \
}                                                                                                                           \
Redirector<void,__VA_ARGS__>NAME ## HandlerObject("_"#NAME, reinterpret_cast<Redirector<void,__VA_ARGS__>::FuncTy>(NAME));

REGISTER_HANDLER(foo,int);
REGISTER_HANDLER(bar,double, int*);
```

If someone has a better idea please let me know.